# Exponential Growth (Number of bacteria..)

Tags: calculus

I tried, but I am not sure if I am heading toward the right path. Here is the question.

The number of bacteria $N$ in a culture after $t$ hours is modeled by the exponential growth curve.

$N = N_0e^{rt}$

A) If the population of the culture grew from $200$ to $2300$ in $18$ hours, find the average growth rate $r$.

For this what I did was I set $N= 2300$ and $N_0=200$ and $18$ for Time$(t)$. So

$2300 = 200e^{r(18)}$ 
Then I divided $200$ to both side and got

$23/2 = e^{r(18)}$ and took ln of both side.. and I got weird answer.. I am not sure if I got it right up to here, and I also have to find the answer to part $b$ which is,

B) Assuming that the growth rate $r$ is constant, determine what the population will be in another $6$ hours.?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First part is correct. The second part asks what the population will be after another 6 hours if the growth rate $r$ is independent of the time elapsed and is also equal to the average growth rate (which you just calculated).